# How to expire Rails conditional GET caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, http-caching

I'm using the `stale?` method to do conditional GET caching in my JSON API.

I use

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
if stale? @post
  #continue
end
```

AFAIK This uses the post's updated_at to make a cache key. Is there any way I can expire the cache entry for this item without doing post.touch? I'm using Heroku.

Comment: are you using some kind of http cache proxy like rack-cache and setting the s-maxage such that the request doesn't hit the stack?

Comment: @JesseGoodfellow No, I don't think so. The request definitely hits the stack, because the `stale?` method is used in my Post Controller

Comment: For what cache are you trying to expire the entries?  Browser cache?  Are you saying you want to respond with a 200 even though the record hasn't changed?  Or is the record being modified but still responding with a 304?  If the stale? method uses an etag, you could expire all etags in your app by modifying the ENV['RAILS_CACHE_ID'] variable

Comment: @JesseGoodfellow Yes, basically I made a change to how the api response looks. The model/record itself hasn't changed. So I want to be able to stop sending a 304 NOT MODIFIED and send a 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a file in config/initializers called bust_cache.rb with following contents:

```
ENV["RAILS_CACHE_ID"] = 'version1'
```

If in future you wish to bust the cache again change the value to 'version2' etc.  If you wish to bust the cache with every deploy use:

```
ENV["RAILS_CACHE_ID"] = Time.now.to_s
```

***Note that this last strategy will not work with multiple dynos on Heroku or other such similar situations

thanks to [Nathan Kontny](http://ninjasandrobots.com/how-to-bust-your-rails-etag-cache-on-deployment)

Comment: Thanks, haven't tested it yet but it seems like it will work.